# Gdrive api: how can i get the folder name or directory of a file

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using GDrive api (java) for getting files from GDrive. I can get all files from the Gdrive.I can't get the directory or folder for a particular file. suppose if i have a file '**test.txt**' in **root folder** as well as some other folder called **Sample**. In my code GDrive's *files().list()* method returns both files. Here i want to get the Sample folder's '**test.txt**' file. How can i achieve this.

Comment: Does the reply of @Scarygami answer your question? If yes, please confirm it!

Answer (score 5):

Two ways you can go about this.

1. Checking `parents` for each returned file.

   Each file resource in the response will have a property `parents` which is an array of [parent resources](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents#resource) with an ID for the folder. You can use this folder ID with a `files.get` request to check if it is the folder you are looking for.
2. Searching only files in one folder.

   Get the ID of the folder first by doing a `files.list` looking only for the Sample folder by name. You can limit your search to folders only by adding `mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'` to the query.

   You can then use the ID of the folder in a [`children.list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list) request with the name of your file as query parameter.

Comment: If one is using the Java API like me don't forget the call to execute() on the Get object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'path': "/drive/v2/files?q=title contains 'my title' ",
```